# Customize Apache and IIS Webserver responses

Tags: apache, http, iis, httpd.conf

Is there a way to set customized responses on Apache webserver (httpd) and/or IIS? The requirement is to test the behavior of our service on a HTTP response w/o terminating CRLF i.e:

**I want**

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently\r\n
Location: https://abc.com/\r\n
```

**And not**

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently\r\n
Location: https://abc.com/\r\n
\r\n
```

For now, I am using a workaround of having a custom webserver written in python.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure how to get that functionality from Apache or IIS. Is there a reason it has to be one of those two, and not your python server, or even piping a canned response into [nc](http://linux.die.net/man/1/nc)?

Comment: @pieman72: There is no specific reason for doing it via Apache or IIS. I was just curios to know if it is a possibility. My Python server is doing well. And yes, thanks for sharing about "nc". I will explore it further.